# Furigana possibly broken in Firefox 29.0?

Tags: discussion, furigana

I have two computers, both running Ubuntu 14.04, and Firefox 29.0. On both computers, the furigana is not displaying for me. It was working up until very recently, and possibly stopped working with the update from version 28 to 29. Or possibly when upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04. Both happened within the last two weeks or so. I didn't really notice when the furigana stopped working, but it would be within that time frame.

I just now tested using Chrome, and furigana is displaying fine. So, it would seem there is a problem with furigana displaying in Firefox 29, at least on Ubuntu Linux. Is anyone else seeing this, or is it just me?

Is this a bug, or something I can address with my browser settings? I have cleared the cache and history, and restarted the browser, but that has not helped.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm also using Firefox 29.0 on Ubuntu 14.04, but I can't reproduce the problem. Does the "furigana options" text near the bottom of each page display properly? Also, if you use the firebug console tab (by pressing the `F12` key after installing it from https://getfirebug.com/), are there any errors?

Comment: I checked it on Windows 7 and Firefox 29.0.1. All is fine for me.

Comment: @cypher, No errors in Firebug. Also, I don't have any "furigana options" at the bottom of the screen anymore. They definitely used to be there. I do see the "furigana options" at the bottom of the screen in Chrome.

Comment: @cypher, I just discovered what it is. I had a [Firefox extension called "Privacy Badger"](https://www.eff.org/privacybadger) from the Electronic Frontier Foundation. Disabling it has made furigana work again. Not sure why it would interfere with furigana, though. It's supposed to just block sites that try and track personal data. I wonder what it is about the furigana feature that causes Privacy Badger to respond negatively.

Comment: It's probably because the Furigana script is hosted at sstatic.net (http://sstatic.net/js/third-party/japanese-l-u.js?v=6) rather than japanese.stackexchange.com, and was detecting it as an external tracking website and blocking it. Exactly why it would do this I don't know, but as the other SE-related JS seems to be linked to as `cdn.sstatic.net` rather than a straight `sstatic.net` for some reason it's possible the main SE JS might still work while the Furigana engine won't with Privacy Badger on. I'm afraid there might not be much I can do about this if it's blanket blocking that domain.

Comment: Maybe the stack exchange people could make the link to the Furigana engine `<script src="//cdn.sstatic.net/js/third-party/japanese-l-u.js?v=6"></script>` and see if that fixes it. It might also have to do with the way `localStorage` is used like a cookie to store the Furigana settings, but I don't know. (BTW, I've downloaded Privacy Badger and can't seem to trigger this problem with it. Obviously there's some reason for this happening, but I don't know exactly what it could be).

Comment: @cypher, I'm unclear on how one would go about reporting this to the right people at SE. It seems like something they may want to adjust as you suggest.

Comment: It looks like I was on the right track: `cdn.sstatic.net` is on the [Privacy Badger whitelist](https://github.com/EFForg/privacybadgerchrome/blob/master/sample_cookieblocklist.txt) for sites that provide essential third party resources, but `sstatic.net` is not. I don't know how it should be reported exactly either, but I'll flag a comment - maybe one of the moderators will know.

Comment: @DaveMG: Generally speaking, bugs are reported exactly like this. The issue is partly that this is a 'bug' in that an optional plugin for a browser has problems with the domain they're using.

Comment: @cypher: Given that comment, I suspect stackexchange's position is going to be that it's a Privacy Badger bug (not whitelisting sstatic.net), as opposed to a SE bug... but I'm not all that familiar with such things.